# Android :audio issue

Tags: android, audio

when i click a button,an audio get played,but if at the same time i play another audio clip in my app the first one didn't stop,but both audio clip runs at the same time.This problem exists in the case if i click the button multiple times,multiple instances of audio file runs.I want to run only one audio file at a time.if i click another audio file,then previous audio file should be automatically stopped.

java file code is

```
button_audio2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            mysound = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.audio2);
           if( mysound.isPlaying()){
               button_audio2.setText("play");
               mysound.pause();}
            else{
               button_audio2.setText("pause");
               mysound.start();
               mysound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       mp.release();
                   }
               })
               ;
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The `MediaPlayer` object has an `isPlaying` and a `stop` method.

Comment: isPlaying() or setOnCompletionListener()?

Comment: isPlaying is not working in my code..i've pasted my code above again...but it is not working..

Comment: `mysound = MediaPlayer.create` is making a new mediaplayer each time you click on `button_audio2 `. You might want to do a check `if (mysound == null)`

Comment: yes,....it's working now...thanks a lot Hacketo

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your post, each time you click on the button this create a new MediaPlayer

You might do a little change in your code to test if `mysound` is already initialized.

```
button_audio2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if (mysound == null){
            mysound = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.audio2);
            mysound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   mp.release();
                   mysound = null;
               }
            });
        }
        if( mysound.isPlaying()){
            button_audio2.setText("play");
            mysound.pause();
        }
        else{
            button_audio2.setText("pause");
            mysound.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: by this code that problem is solved now...but it is causing new problem..after completion of audio when i again try to run audio by clicking the button app crashes.  exception is:                                                                                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
            at com.baswal.neeraj.myfirstapp.MyActivity$2.onClick(MyActivity.java:72)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)

Comment: I edited the code, adding `mysound = null`, this will recreate a new MediaPlayer, if you dont want to release the mediaplayer you 'll have to add `mp.reset();` instead of `mp.release();` and `mysound = null;`

Comment: @neerajbaswal if my answer helped you, feel free to accept it

Comment: @neerajbaswal just in case, there is a button that you can click to mark an answer as accepted (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)